# How to normalize a file path opened from the quickfix?

Tags: vim-plugin, neovim, vim-quickfix

I am using NeoVim v0.7.2 (also tested with v0.6.1) on Windows 10 in git-bash, with [vim-dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) to allow for asynchronous builds (building a C++ codebase with Clang).

When there are errors in the build, the quickfix is correctly populated, but the file paths might not be normalized (e.g. `src\lib\..\lib\Header.h`).

When `Header.h` is already opened in another NeoVim window via NerdTree, the window names uses the normalized name `src\lib\Header.h`.

Then, if I try to jump from the error in the quickfix, NeoVim attempts to open the same file in another window with a different name (the **non** normalized path).

This causes a host of issues, notably because the swap file for this file is already present. I would like to have it jump to the already opened window on the file if it exists, or to open it with the normalized name if it does not.

Can it be achieved?

---

I already have this option in my `init.vim`:

```
set switchbuf=useopen,usetab,newtab
```